# Что поправить в php коде wordpress, чтобы пропало уведомление?

Tags: php, wordpress

Появляется уведомление, подскажите, пожалуйста, что поправить?

```
Notice: Undefined index: extra_fields_nonce in /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 51 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php:51)
```

вот 51 строка:
`if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['extra_fields_nonce'], __FILE__) ) return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить проверку на существование ключа в массиве

```
if ( ! isset( $_POST['extra_fields_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['extra_fields_nonce'], __FILE__) ) return false;
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что доктор прописал